# Optimal zoom level in Android Google Maps API version 2

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I am developing an android app in which I display users location (markers) in Google map.

In Google Maps API version_1, to get optimal zoom level I have used the similar code explained in [Android how to calculate optimal zoom level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642315/android-how-to-calculate-optimal-zoom-level). Using this, I had all markers in the same view and Zoom level worked properly when I had one or many markers.

However in Android Google Maps API version_2:

```
mapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(aLocationBuilder.build(), 50));
```

I tried the above code. When I have many markers, the above code worked properly and displayed all markers in the same view (with proper zoom level).

However when I have only one marker, it zoomed to its maximum. It must not be so. How can I get the optimal zoom level for Maps API version_2.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

When you have only one marker, use `newLatLngZoom` version of the factory. Set `LatLng` to the position of your `Marker` and zoom to value of 21.

Comment: Thanks for the reply MaciejGórski.. Actually the marker count varies dynamically. Sometimes I have one marker and some times I have many. When I have many markers, the above code works perfectly. However, when I have one marker, I have this zoom issue. Is there any way through which can I find the markers count or LocationBuilder size, so that I can change my code accordingly. Please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: @Kamal I don't know what a `LocationBuilder` is, but if you mean `LatLngBounds.Builder` then there is no way except for checking if bottom left and top right `LatLng` is the same.

Comment: You could calculate the bounds of all the Markers and zoom out to fit them in, here is an excerpt of something I wrote for Maps v3 in Javascript. I'm sure you could use it for Android with a bit of tweaking

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the bounds of all the Markers and zoom out to fit them in, here is an excerpt of something I wrote for Maps v3 in Javascript. I'm sure you could use it for Android with a bit of tweaking

```
//Make an array of the LatLng's of the markers you want to show
var LatLngList = new Array (new google.maps.LatLng (52.537,-2.061), new    google.maps.LatLng (52.564,-2.017));

//  Create a new viewpoint bound
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();

//  Go through each...
for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = LatLngList.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
  //  And increase the bounds to take this point
  bounds.extend (LatLngList[i]);
}

//  Fit these bounds to the map
map.fitBounds (bounds);
```